# Efficient way to check if user exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a simple query to check if users with specific credential exist in the database, if so throw an error.

```
    $user_exists_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE phone=:phone OR email=:email AND status=:status ";
    $check_user_exists = $conn->prepare($user_exists_query);
    $check_user_exists->bindValue(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check_user_exists->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check_user_exists->bindValue(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check_user_exists->execute();
```

The above works, but fails in some scenario such as some users don't have email adress and the row is empty but the query returns all of them. What I would like to have is the query returns only the count of users that have either a phone or a email that matches the condition. Not returning for when the row is empty. How can I come with such solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It might help to include sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @showdev as the question title says, I need to check if users with same phone number and/or email exist then I throw and error message. But the problem comes when for example email is empty but phone has value, the query returns all users even though the phone doesn't match any

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes, tried that already, still returning all the users that don't have an email adress, because email is empty in the clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to build the query string in PHP to include only parameters with non-empty values.

```
// define parameter array
$params = [];

// add trimmed values to parameter array
if (!empty($phone) && !ctype_space($phone)) {
    $params['phone'] = trim($phone);
}
if (!empty($email) && !ctype_space($email)) {
    $params['email'] = trim($email);
}

// build where statement from parameter array
$wheres = implode(' OR ',array_map(function($v){return "`$v`=:$v";},array_keys($params)));

// build full query
$user_exists_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE ($wheres) AND status=:status;";

// prepare statement
$check_user_exists = $conn->prepare($user_exists_query);

// bind parameter values
foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
    $check_user_exists->bindValue(":$k", $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

// bind status value
$check_user_exists->bindValue(':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

// execute
$check_user_exists->execute();
```

Another method is to exclude blank values in the query itself.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE 
  (
    (
      phone = : phone 
      AND phone != ''
    ) 
    OR (
      email = : email 
      AND email != ''
    )
  ) 
  AND status = : status
```